# how to produce multi-frame .js file with multiple textures for webGL

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl, kinect

I'm filming actions with kinect and generating mesh models with textures.
Each frame is saved as a ply model with a texture image.
I want to display the 3D video in webGL environment.
I have tried with .js files which is able to display animated 3D models, however all the frames in these models uses one texture throughout all the frames.

Now I'm not sure what will the .js file formats be like if each frame of the model uses a different texture image.
Does anyone know about the format or can point me to some documents about it?

Or, if .js isn't the best format to achieve such effect, what would be a more appropriate format for displaying kinect generated 3D video(mesh+texture)?

Thanks!